# Provide an unambiguous context-free grammar for a language $L$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Firstly, let $L = \{ w \in \Sigma \cup \{ \varepsilon, (,), +, ., ^* \}^* \mid w $ is a syntactically legal regular expression over $\Sigma \} $.

I need to give an **unambiguous context-free grammar** that generates L. The question notes that the grammar should use the following precedence levels, from highest to lowest: (1) $^*$ (Kleene star), (2) $.$ (concatenation), and (3) $+$ (union).

While this makes sense, I am unclear on precedence.

The question goes on to ask for a parse tree for the newly created grammar that produces for the string $a(a+b)^*$ .

Does anyone know where to begin with this? I feel like I understand [context-free grammars](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/grammars/cfg.html) but ensuring unambiguous and precedence is a bit confusing.

Comment: The way this is written, it does not look like ',' is a character, just that a comma is separating the parentheses. This is confirmed by the fact that there is no rule for ',' defined in your precedences (1)-(3)

Comment: You are correct.